# Why does Apache Redirect with relative URL work in OSX but not CentOS?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

Trying to do something simple here, but having a great deal of difficulty

**.htaccess**

```
Redirect 301 /foo-bar /foobar
```

This works on OSX but CentOS complains that I'm not using a full URL.

CentOS wants

```
Redirect 301 /foo-bar http://example.com/foobar
```

I don't want to specify the the full host name for each URL.

Both OSX and CentOS are running Apache `2.2.x`

Is there some way to accomplish this?

---

Update:

I've tried `RewriteRule` and it doesn't even seem to work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/foo-bar$ /foobar [R=301,L]
```

The match isn't even made and now I'm getting a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Apparently apache doesn't support relative urls in the target of a `Redirect` until `2.2.6`

My CentOS is running `2.2.3` so that's was the problem there

---

My attempt at using `RewriteRule` was also incorrect. The following will work as intended

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo-bar$ /foobar [R=301,L]
```

Note the leading `/` is removed from my original question

---

Long story short, you can use `Redirect` with relative urls if your apache is `>= 2.2.6`

```
Redirect 301 /foo-bar /foobar
```

Or use `RewriteRule` if you are stuck on an older version

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo-bar$ /foobar [R=301,L]
```